# Copy RAW codec from different macOS versions

Tags: macos, photos

Is there a method to copy the system codec for RAW format from a later macOS to a oldest? **Where and how they are stored?**

The problem is that I've a Nikon D5600 but their RAW/NEF file can't be recognised by the codecs of macOS 10.11 and at the same time I cant' update my system to the 10.12.4. And Nikon doesn't provide downloadable codec for macOS.

Comment: Did you install the Nikon suite of software, ViewNX-i, Transfer, Capture, etc? The codecs probably are in there.

Comment: Codecs aren't comprised in Nikon software...

Comment: I have no issues here - 3 Macs, 10.11, 10.13 & 10.14. All can quicklook .nef files. The 10.13 machine, afaik, has never had any Nikon software on it. The only 'codec pack' for Mac was Perian, which went unsupported a long time ago. Might be worth a try... https://perian.org

Comment: Just found this - up to D5500 files are natively supported in El Capitan. https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/eu/BV_article?articleNo=000004911&configured=1&lang=en_GB If D5600 files really are that different, then you might need to think about converting to .dng instead, or just work in ViewNX-i with export to .tiff [file size will go up a lot though] I have a D5500, that might just make all the difference. Forget Perian, btw, it's a video codec pack, not stills.

Comment: yes, but then I have problems with Aperture that seems to be non longer suppored... It's a trap...

Comment: Yeah, Aperture is gone - but tbh the only photo app that will actually show you "the photo you think you took" is ViewNX-i. I do all my culling in there, export as TIF then deal in Photoshop. Once I'm in Ps I then trash the intermediate TIF, because ViewNX-i has the sidecar files it can easily regenerate the TIF in seconds, should I ever need it.